# Trying to Save a Java GUI as an Image in higher resolution

Tags: java, image

I am new to Stack Overflow but not new to programming. I am writing a java project for my own personal use, and maybe for some friends. I create a GUI, and add some images to a collage, and then I want to save it as a JPG that will scale to print nicely on an 8 1/2 x 11 paper (landscape).

I found the following code by asaren08 on Github, which works fine but the jpg is lower resolution. I need something of print quality.

I create my collage in an ImagePanel shown in the class below, it looks nice. I save it and print it and it is low resolution. I understand that is because my screen is lower resolution than my printer. If I create it pretending my resolution is 300 DPI, then it shows up on my screen scaled to fit, and that is what it saves, which is not what I want! It is not even proportional. For example, my laptop monitor is 15 inches -ish, wide and short. My image comes out wider than it should, exactly what I see on my monitor, but I want to to come out the way I set it, not the way it shows up on my monitor. On the other hand, I need to be able to see the GUI to set up my collage...

Any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * Save the Panel as image with the name and the type in parameters
 *
 * @param name name of the file
 * @param type type of the file
 */
public void saveImage(String name,String type) {
    System.out.println("width of image panel ="+getWidth());
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(),getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    paint(g2);
    try{
        ImageIO.write(image, type, new File(name+"."+type));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}

}
```

Update: I added my ImagePanel to a JScrollPane as suggested in the comments. That makes it hard to see where I'm at in my collage. So for now, my silly solution is to put a little thumbnail above the ImagePanel to show what the whole thing looks like and I can see from that where I'm sitting on the ImagePanel.

[image: Screenshot of the collage project]

Comment: You have to leave margins on an 8 1/2 x 11 sheet of paper.  Assuming 1/2 inch margins all around and printing in landscape mode, your image works out to be 10 x 7 1/2.  At 300 pixels per inch, that means the JPEG image you create has to be 3000 by 2250 pixels.  That's almost as large as a 4K monitor.  If your monitor has a lower resolution, you'll have to put the drawing `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is going to work. I just have to debug it. My monitor has a higher resolution, but it isn't showing up when I get the pixels per inch from the Toolkit

Comment: That is, using   Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
  screen_pixels_per_inch = tk.getScreenResolution ();

Comment: So it definitely works. Thank you. But I can't see the whole collage scaled down as I'm working on it even when I minimize it. There has to be a way to change the view without changing the innards.

Comment: *But I can't see the whole collage* - isn't that why you use the JScrollPane? *even when I minimize it* - not sure what that means. I don't see any special logic. Post an [mre] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't making sense.  What I am doing right now is saving a little thumbnail as I go and show that in the main panel so that I can see which part of the scrollpane I'm sitting at. Thanks for your help. The scrollpane definitely solves the resolution problem.  If I can figure out how to add an image I'll show a screenshot.

Comment: I updated the original problem with a picture of my current solution. It's not ideal but it will work.

Comment: One way to "scale down the image" is to shrink it down to a 1:4 scale for display in a `JDialog`.  An image 750 by 612 pixels should show enough detail to be useful and fit on most current monitors.